# asia-southeast1-b computer engine down

Tags: linux, shutdown

2019-02-07 19:52:12.748 JST asia-southeast1-b computer engine down.

event_subtype:  "compute.instances.hostError"
event_type:  "GCE_OPERATION_DONE"

What caused the server down?

How does google solve it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror

> **There was a host error with my virtual machine and it was restarted. What happened?**
>
> A host error means that there was a hardware or software issue on the physical machine hosting your virtual machine that caused your virtual machine to crash. When Compute Engine detects such an event, we add a `compute.instances.hostError` entry to your operations log. If your virtual machine is set to automatically restart, which is the default, Google will also restart your virtual machine on a different physical machine.
>
> In general, physical hardware failures and software failures can happen from time-to-time, but are rare occurrences. To protect your applications and services from potentially disruptive system events like these, make sure you design robust systems and build scalable and resilient web applications. Use managed instance groups to perform health checking and scaling across groups of Compute Engine instances.